# Как добавить доп.поля в wordpress запись?

Tags: php, wordpress

Столкнулся с проблемой.

Сперва суть: натягиваю сайт на котором есть [кейсы, статьи]
со статьями всё понятно, но у меня возникла проблема с кейсами
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я выделил все поля, которые будут меняться,и у меня Дилемма: Сделать это как статью, но при её открытии будет переадресация на пдф.

Тогда я не знаю куда вписать Данные в красных кружках, чтобы после их взять при выводе всех кейсов.

Или сделать собственное расширение, которое будет запрашивать все эти поля.

Кейс не подходит как статья и при открытии всё равно будет переадресация на pdf файл.

у кого есть предложения ?

Comment: Создать не публичный кастом пост тайп.

Comment: ну а данные в кружках откуда брать?

Comment: А в записи Вы их откуда брали? Из custom fields, очевидно. Установите ACF или любой его аналог.

Comment: Спасибо, я понял. просто ещё не работал с WP и всё в первый раз )